# How do I request search results from google without trigerring a 429 error( too many requests for url)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-429

My script makes only one request from 'www.google.com/search?q=' despite this it always triggers a 429 error( too many requests for url). The script simply attempts to use python's 3rd party requests library to retrieve the search page for a word entered as a command line variable. Solutions I have tried include adding a header specifying my user agent.This is all of the code it is quite small.

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4

headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0' }
print('Googling...') # display text while downloading the Google page
res = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]), headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()
```

The error reads as follows

```
  File "lucky.py", line 11, in <module>
    res.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url: https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dred&q=EgRmsF6JGJ_0-48GIhDND5xins41tXhPPRNDx_-jMgFy
```

Thanks

Edited***

So the code runs when I use an online compiler but not on my PC...

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8q1F.png) .

> HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests * this occurs because server blocks the ip temporary as it thinks you are trying to spam something by sending to many requests in a short amount of time. It's  a security measurement by the server

Comment: I guess your ip is blocked  :(

Comment: Try a VPN  you can use free ones like windscribe on your machine

Comment: Yes... A VPN on your machine changes the IP for the whole machine...... But you can also use proxies have a look here https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/python-requests-proxy/

Comment: The vpn works I guess but it didn't solve the problem... sigh I'm going try something else thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a while back that the problem was caused by my OS settings and the solution is a rather simple thing. I'm run windows 10 by the way.
All you need to do is
Go to settings -> Click on network & internet -> Click VPN (its on the sidebar) -> and turn off the system VPN
It worked fine after this. So the problem was the windows default VPN, it doesn't pair well with automated google searches for some reason. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).